# python - How to share files between many computers

Tags: python

My python process run on different machines. It consists of a manager and many workers. The worker in each machine are multi threaded and needs to update some data such as its status  to the manager residing on another machine. I didn't want to use mysql because many other processes are already executing many queries on it and it will reach its max_connection

I have two methods in mind:

1. For each worker thread, write the data to a local text file. A separate bash script will run a while-loop, check for file change and scp this file to all other machines.
2. For each worker thread, write the data to share memory and have it replicated to all other machines. I am not sure how to do this. In python how can i write to shared memory? How can i replicated shared memories?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, first point is that you can't share memory among *machines* unless you're on a very specialized architecture. (Massively parallel machines, Beowulf clusters, and so on.)

If you mean to share *code*, then package your code into a real Python package and distribute it with a tool like Chef, Puppet or Docker.

If you mean to share *data*, use a database of some sort that all your workers can access. I'm fond of MongoDB because it's easy to match to an application, but there are a million others databases.  A lot of people use mysql or postgresql.

Comment: I have about 100 threads per worker. Each worker thread will need to update data such as its status to the manager.  If i use mysql, I will reach the limit of max_connection

Comment: @nuttynibbles A database seems like the right approach though. Perhaps you should ask a [tag: mysql] question about dealing with max connection limit.

Comment: Well, that's just another reason I like MongoDB.  But if that's really an issue, you really should consider a server, or a few servers, using a RESTful interface.  They're really intended for managing just that with a **lot** more than 100 concurrent users.